# What should i do when offset fetch not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me I think it is in correct syntax.
But why it alerts me incorrect in SQL Server 2017

```
SELECT Request  
FROM TD_TD  
ORDER BY Request  
OFFSET 1 ROWS    
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Looks like SQL Server wants a parameter, not a calculation.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I need to calculate them

Comment: Something like `OFFSET p1 FETCH FIRST p2 ROWS ONLY`. BTW, start with removing that `rows` keyword before `fetch first`.

Comment: I have tried but it still show message the same

Comment: Should we answer you in pictures, too?

Comment: Sure Help me please

Comment: Should be `FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY` and not `FETCH FIRST x ROWS ONLY`

Comment: Also, Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I try to read but I cannot find out any way to solve.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Could you send me image via Email for the solution?

Comment: first you make sure the query is working with constant number first. without using variable. When that works, you substitute it with the variables like  `@pageno` etc

Comment: I try as your comment but it still show syntax error.

Comment: @PatamonTK stop adding images... post code and errors as **`text`**. Please read Zohar's comment with the link and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

`OFFSET` syntax is `OFFSET {Rows} ROWS`. you're missing the `ROWS` key word.

The isn't your SQL, as it's an image, however, the correct syntax in Pseudo-SQL would be (but i didn't follow JohnyL's comment and answer in an image ):

```
SELECT {Your Coloumns}
FROM YourTable YT
ORDER BY {Order Columns}
OFFSET @OffSetVar ROWS --You're missing ROWS
FETCH FIRST @FirstVar ROWS ONLY;
--Above could also be replaced with (they are semantically the same)
--FETCH NEXT @NextVAR ROWS ONLY;
```

The documentationm has a great example: [Specifying expressions for OFFSET and FETCH values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-specifying-expressions-for-offset-and-fetch-values)

The SQL you have in your post does not generate an error:

```
CREATE TABLE #TD_TD(Request int);
INSERT INTO #TD_TD (Request)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),
       (11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),
       (21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30);


SELECT Request  
FROM #TD_TD  
ORDER BY Request  
OFFSET 1 ROWS    
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
GO

DROP TABLE #TD_TD;
```

This return the values 2 - 21

Comment: @PatamonTK there are several images above, which one?.. Like everyone has commented, don't use images. Post code as `text` and then post your errors as a quote.

Comment: Sorry Sir, It's My bad

SELECT a.request_id FROM [packing_spec].[dbo].[TD_Issue] a 
ORDER BY a.request_id
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY

Comment: @PatamonTK that's *still* an image.

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: Also, @PatamonTK the SQL you have doesn't generate an error. See my updated post.

Comment: What does? Have you run the query I provided above? It runs fine (I literally tested it). What is the error? Read everyone's comments and when you have done, update your post. The *only* other thing i can think of that is the problem is you're using an old version of SQL Server, and `OFFSET` syntax *(not systex)* doesn't exist in it; but without knowing the version of SQL Server you are using that is impossible to comment on.

Comment: I have use SQL version 14

Comment: @PatamonTK `OFFSET` works fine on SQL Server 2017. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b6e1/2) (fiddle uses SQL Server 2017 syntax). I'm not pointing you to the comments again; if you aren't going to consume the information in them then the volunteers here can't help you.

Comment: Sorry SQL version 17.1
My bad

Comment: There is not SQL Server 17. The latest version is 14 (SQL Server 2017). There isn't a 14.1 release yet, as SP1 hasn't yet been released. If you are saying you are using 17.1 are you SURE you are using SQL Server?

Comment: it named SQL 2017 but version 14.0